# How to get notified when unfiltered Netty server actually gets shutdown?

Tags: scala, testing, netty, unfiltered

I have an Unfiltered Netty server that I need to shutdown and restart after every test.

```
val mockService = unfiltered.netty.Server.http(mockServicePort).handler(mockServicePlan)

before {
  proxyServer.start()
}

after {
  proxyServer.stop()
}
```

Currently, this is not working, and I am fairly certain that is because the `stop()` function is non-blocking and so the following `start()` function gets called to early.

I looked for a way to block or get notified on server closure, but it would not appear to be surfaced through the current API.

Is there a better way of achieving what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer: replace your Unfiltered Netty server with a HTTP4S Blaze server.

```
var server: org.http4s.server.Server = null

val go: Task[Server] = org.http4s.server.blaze.BlazeBuilder
  .bindHttp(mockServicePort)
  .mountService(mockService)
  .start

before {
  server = go.run
}

after {
  server.shutdown.run
}
```

There's also an `awaitShutdown` that blocks until the server shuts down. But since `shutdown` is a `Task`, it's easy to get notified when it has finished. Just `flatMap` that shit.

Comment: That's funny, I was discussing this with Guillaume Massé last night and he suggested the same thing. I never worked with http4s before, but after taking a look at it, it does look pretty nifty. Was going to run it by the team this morning and make the switch unless someone convinced me otherwise but I guess you beet me to the punch!

Comment: I don't think Nathan is maintaining unfiltered anymore anyway.